Nonce value not included only when using nonce as key (EJS)
// I create a nonce
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  next();
});

// I pass the nonce to my views (ESJ) where I access it:
<p><%= nonce %></p>
<script nonce="<%=nonce%>" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

For a Node Express app, this code correctly displays the nonce value for the p element, but the script line is compiled as:
<script nonce="" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

If I change the key in the script line to anything else then nonce, it does display the nonce value:
<script nonce222="someValue" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

What might be causing this strange behavior? How to make the nonce work?

see Google Chrome Stripping nonce values from script tags
